# Filter numpy array but keep original value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray, boolean-indexing

In other words, does numpy support 'sieving'?

I have two arrays:

```
a = np.array([1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 4])
b = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6])
```

What I want is to return a new array, `c`, that contains the original values of `a` based on the mask of `b`:

```
c = a[b > 0] 
>> c
np.array([1, 4])
# but what I want is:
# np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4])
```

I can get around this by doing a list comprehension:

```
c = [a[i] if b[i] > 0 else 0 for i in range(len(a))]
```

I could also make a mask, but that would require 2x iteration:

```
mask = [1 if b[i] > 0 else 0 for i in range(len(b))]  
c = ma.array(a, mask=mask)
```

Is there something native to numpy that allows one array to act like a sieve for another array?

Comment: How is a list comprehension "getting around". Is there something special you do not like about it? IMO it is the simplest and most readable solution. I would as well use zip just to make even more clear `[a if b > 0 else 0 for a, b in zip(a,b)] `.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
result = np.where(b > 0, a, 0)
print(result)
```

Or just multiply:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 0, 2, 3, 0, 4])
b = np.array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6])

print(a * (b > 0))
```

**Output**

```
[1 0 0 0 0 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Another idea would be to initialize the result array `c` with zeroes (based on the shape of `a`) and then use a boolean mask to fill in the values from `a`. Below is an illustration:

```
# result array
In [28]: c = np.zeros_like(a)  

# get the indices where nonzero values exist in array `b`
In [29]: nonzero_idx = np.nonzero(b)  

# extract the corresponding values from the array `a` and
# fill in the array `c` using the same indices
In [30]: c[nonzero_idx] = a[nonzero_idx] 

In [31]: c 
Out[31]: array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4])
```

---

The explanation for the case of using [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
In [42]: np.where(b >  0, *[a, 0])   
Out[42]: array([1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4])
```

the part `b > 0` is the condition that we're gonna check, with the entries in the array `a`. If this condition is satisfied, then those elements would be returned, else we a `0` would be returned; this is why we pass 0 as a third argument to [`numpy.where()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

If you want some other values to be filled in instead of `0`s, then pass the desired value. For example, let's say we want a `-9` to be filled in the places where the condition (`b > 0`) is not satisfied (i.e. `False`), then we would write something like:

```
In [43]: np.where(b >  0, *[a, -9])     
Out[43]: array([ 1, -9, -9, -9, -9,  4])
```